# PHP & HTML: How to include .php in concatenated PHP string var

Tags: php, html, string, variables, include

Example of what i am trying to do:

```
<?php
 $html_element = '<form><label>country</label><select>'.include_once("country_list.php").'</select></form>';
?>
```

I have tried the above and the following:

```
<?php
 $html_element = '<form><label>country</label><select><?php include_once("country_list.php"); ?></select></form>';
?>
```

Of course the "$html_element" is then echoed in some div later. So how can i include the "country_list.php" in this php string variable so that it will pull correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to include the data, no matter which file type it is, do like this:

```
<?php
 $html_element = '<form><label>country</label><select>'.file_get_contents("country_list.php").'</select></form>';
?>
```

Comment: thanks that in fact did work, so it was the include_once() function that was incorrect for this scenario.

Comment: what is in country_list.php? just html or is there actual php to parse? @sage_x10